# Overflowing on top of table rows instead of under

Tags: css, overflow, cell, z-index, css-tables

I've got a situation where a `div` is overflowing out of a `td`. The problem is that it is somehow flowing *underneath* the content that is below it, which makes everything illegible. I tried using `z-index` to no avail. See my **[jsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/htn2x/)**.

```
td.big { 
    overflow-y:visible;
}
div.clipper { 
    max-height: 5em; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
div.clipper:hover {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
tr:hover,
div.clipper:hover .backing {
    background: lightblue;
    z-index: 1;
}

table, tr, td { 
    z-index: 0;
}
```

I'm aware that technically `td` shouldn't have `overflow` at all. My real goal here is to prevent the content of certain cells from getting larger than a certain height, and then displaying that content on hover. Is there a CSS only solution to this, or am I going to have to do the whole `$.clone()` thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `max-height: inherit;` to .clipper:hover.

```
div.clipper:hover {
    overflow-y: visible;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: `max-height: none;` is also ok.

Comment: I guess I should have specified that I don't want the row to ever change height.

Answer (score 0):

z-index does not work by default. It only works on relative, absolute or fixed positioned elements.
When you add `position: relative` to the css sections where you specift a z-index it works.